# Using AfterSubmit UserEventScript with SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm pretty new to SuiteScript 2.0, so far it has been an insane learning experience.

Currently I am trying to write a script that will take a new Item Fulfillment record that is just being created, get the newly generated ID and place that value onto another record.  I have been trying to test this by setting the value of a field on the same record with no luck.  The script will run, but nothing sticks.  The field I am setting the value of always remains blank.

/**

- @NapiVersion 2.0
- @NScriptType UserEventScript
  */

define(['N/record'],

```
function(record) {
    
    function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {
        
        if (scriptContext.type !== scriptContext.UserEventType.CREATE)
            return;
        
        var rec = scriptContext.newRecord;
        
        rec.load({
            type: record.type.ITEMFULFILLMENT,
            id: rec
        });
        
        var itemFul = rec.getValue({
            fieldId : 'tranid'
        });

        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custbody_mod_billoflading_ref',
            value: itemFul
        });
        
        rec.save();

    };

    return{
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Again I am fairly new to SuiteScript 2.0 and learning a ton along the way!  I appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is your UserEvent deployment on an Item Fulfillment?

- If YES, there's no need of loading the record again

However, you will need to load the 'other' record in which you need to set the value. Store the loaded record in a variable

```
var otherRecord = rec.load({
   type: 'OTHER RECORD TYPE'
   id: 'OTHER RECORD ID'
});
```

Also, **you are trying to perform setValue on the current Record (i.e. rec)**

You will need to do setValue on the record you loaded, following a record.save() to save it.

```
otherRecord.setValue({
   fieldId: 'custbody_mod_billoflading_ref'
   value: itemFul //your code variable
});

otherRecord.save();
```

**ALTERNATIVELY,**

You can use record.submitFields() API which would make your life much easier. Syntax is as below -

```
var id = record.submitFields({
 type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
 id: 1,
 values: {
 memo: 'ABC'
 },
 options: {
 enableSourcing: false,
 ignoreMandatoryFields : true
 }
});
```