# Netsuite Customization Requirement

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to accomplish this ?

Scenario: Item fulfillment Record is being created by Shipstation Integration which has Package Content in Format A.

Requirement :
But We want to use that IF record to be exported to another application (Integration) and it mandates the IF record to be in a predefined format not same as Format A.

Please can anyone suggest what is the best possible way to achieve this ? If Suitescripting then which type would work the best.

Answer (score 0):

A suitescript running on After Record Submit either under a [user event script](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2963662.html) or [workflow action script](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4103739018.htm) on the IF sounds like the way to go. It wants to only be triggered on the CREATE (not EDIT, unless you can post updates to your Shipstation integration).

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852756/using-aftersubmit-usereventscript-with-suitescript-2-0) has an example of doing something after submission on an item fulfillment using the User Event Script.